# How to fix PostgreSQL errors telling tid from new index tuple overlaps with invalid duplicate tuple?

Tags: postgresql, database-indexes

When inserting new rows to one of my tables (having multiple indexes) from a Spring-Boot application, I sometimes get:

```
ERROR: table tid from new index tuple (952367,9) overlaps with invalid duplicate tuple at offset 12 of block 49008 in index "foo_index"
ERROR: table tid from new index tuple (952110,19) overlaps with invalid duplicate tuple at offset 22 of block 31693 in index "bar_index"
ERROR: table tid from new index tuple (953430,24) overlaps with invalid duplicate tuple at offset 22 of block 31693 in index "bar_index"
ERROR: table tid from new index tuple (953440,39) overlaps with invalid duplicate tuple at offset 23 of block 31693 in index "bar_index"
ERROR: table tid from new index tuple (952368,27) overlaps with invalid duplicate tuple at offset 76 of block 55849 in index "foo_index"
ERROR: table tid from new index tuple (952368,32) overlaps with invalid duplicate tuple at offset 76 of block 55849 in index "foo_index"
ERROR: table tid from new index tuple (953046,13) overlaps with invalid duplicate tuple at offset 12 of block 49008 in index "foo_index"
```

All these follow a warning `SQL Error: 0, SQLState: XX002`, which means `index_corrupted` according to the [PostgreSQL docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/errcodes-appendix.html).

The server version is `Ubuntu 13.9-1.pgdg22.04+1`.

What can I do to fix it?

Comment: Step 1. Check your backups are good *now*. Have you had any hardware problems/crashes?

Comment: @RichardHuxton Thanks! It's running in Kubernetes (We're using the Zalando Postgres operator to deploy.) and has three nodes. For this particular database, we don't have backups, since an outage of a few hours will not be critical, and all the data in it can be re-created from scratch by re-consuming our Kafka topics again from the beginning. (The database content is a specific projection of our domain events.)

Comment: That looks very much like you upgraded you glibc.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Not that I know of, but thanks! Since only one table is affected (the others seem fine), I hope that [reindexing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76251266/1866775) has fixed it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ran `REINDEX (VERBOSE) TABLE CONCURRENTLY my_table;`. It took ~30 minutes. (The table has ~30M rows.) So far, the errors did not reappear.